# Maven compilation android : Properties not found in android-18. How to resolve this

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to command line execute my android project. Using mvn install -P 4.3

But it shows up an error saying

BBuild Failure. :: Properties not found in android-18.

Comment: Could you post your pom file?

Comment: Figured it out. It was the ANDROID_HOME variable that was creating the problem.